# Libigl example 102 testing error

Tags: ubuntu, cmake, libigl

**I tried to use the libigl on Ubuntu 16.4, but I faced some errors when building the example 102.**

First, I installed the Eigen locating in /usr/local/include/Eigen/.

Then, I downloaded the libigl code following this command:

`git clone --recursive https://github.com/libigl/libigl.git`

Next, I tried to build the Example 102. According to this advice.

`The examples can also be built independently using the CMakeLists.txt inside each example folder.`

So after downloading the source code, I direct build example 102 instead of building the whole tutorial via corresponding CMakeLists.txt locating in /libigl/tutorial/.

**I do like this:**
(1) cd to the folder: ..../libigl/tutorial/102_DrawMesh

(2) mkdir build

(3) cd build

(4) cmake ../

After the cmake ../, I got the following errors, it seems that required links libraries that specified in the CMakeLists.txt locating in ..../libigl/tutorial/102_DrawMesh are not found.

---

The following are the errors:

> -- The C compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
>   -- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
>   -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
>   -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
>   -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
>   -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
>   -- Detecting C compile features
>   -- Detecting C compile features - done
>   -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
>   -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
>   -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
>   -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
>   -- Detecting CXX compile features
>   -- Detecting CXX compile features - done CMake Warning (dev) in CMakeLists.txt:   No cmake_minimum_required command is present.  A
>   line of code such as
>
> ```
> cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
> ```
>
> should be added at the top of the file.  The version specified may
>   be lower   if you wish to support older CMake versions for this
>   project.  For more   information run "cmake --help-policy CMP0000".
>   This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.
>
> -- Configuring done CMake Warning (dev) at CMakeLists.txt:4 (add_executable):   Policy CMP0028 is not set: Double colon in target
>   name means ALIAS or   IMPORTED target.  Run "cmake --help-policy
>   CMP0028" for policy details.   Use the cmake_policy command to set the
>   policy and suppress this warning.
>
> Target "102_DrawMesh_bin" links to target "igl::core" but the target
>   was   not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an
>   IMPORTED   target, or an ALIAS target is missing? This warning is for
>   project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.
>
> CMake Warning (dev) at CMakeLists.txt:4 (add_executable):   Policy
>   CMP0028 is not set: Double colon in target name means ALIAS or
>   IMPORTED target.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0028" for policy
>   details.   Use the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress
>   this warning.
>
> Target "102_DrawMesh_bin" links to target "igl::opengl" but the
>   target was   not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for
>   an IMPORTED   target, or an ALIAS target is missing? This warning is
>   for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.
>
> CMake Warning (dev) at CMakeLists.txt:4 (add_executable):   Policy
>   CMP0028 is not set: Double colon in target name means ALIAS or
>   IMPORTED target.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0028" for policy
>   details.   Use the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress
>   this warning.
>
> Target "102_DrawMesh_bin" links to target "igl::opengl_glfw" but the
>   target   was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for
>   an IMPORTED   target, or an ALIAS target is missing? This warning is
>   for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.
>
> -- Generating done
>   -- Build files have been written to: /home/chayfung/Workspace/Mesh/libigl/tutorial/102_DrawMesh/build
>
> ---
>
> Can someone give me some advice?

Thanks.

Comment: That 4-line `CMakeLists.txt` definitely cannot be built independently: https://github.com/libigl/libigl/blob/6d775fbc1ffc71a9a62c31fae0d8c01455db5382/tutorial/102_DrawMesh/CMakeLists.txt. Not sure why documentation tells so. You may build the parent `CMakeLists.txt` (which corresponds to all examples in the tutorial), and comment unneded examples in it. Note, that you may disable examples for some chapters by setting option `TUTORIALS_CHAPTER<N>` to off. E.g., pass the option `-DTUTORIALS_CHAPTER2=OFF` for `cmake` to disable examples in chapter 2.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thank you for your reply. I follow your advice and try again as following procedures:

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you have sorted out yet. But they can be built independently in the sense that after `cmake` with everything else, the build/`make` procedure can be done independently.

Please follow the usual steps as instructed.

```
cd libigl/tutorial
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ../
```

You can modify the `CMakeLists.txt` in `tutorial` to only make the directory you would like, or use `ccmake ../` to do something ad hoc.

Answer (score 0):

(1) Remove the original source code and download it again, generated a new folder named `libigl`, locating `/mesh/libigl`.

(2) `cd` to the tutorial `/libigl/tutorial/`.

(3) Change the `CMakeList.txt` locating in `/libigl/tutorial/`. I just only disable all the options regarding example chapters, please see the following figures.

[tutorial_CMakeLists_txt-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jrdIR.png)

[tutorial_CMakeLists_txt-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOG81.png)

[tutorial_CMakeLists_txt-3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIUCK.png)

[tutorial_CMakeLists_txt-4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCJ2m.png)

(4) `mkdir build`

(5) `cd build`

(6) `cmake ../`

(7) `make`

(8) In the path `/mesh/libigl/tutorial/build/`, I got the following `.a` libraries. See the following figures. Also in the subfolders, additional `.a` libraries are also generated.

[tutorial_build_libraries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/744ZO.png)

(9) `cd` to the path `/mesh/libigl/tutorial/102_DrawMesh/`

(10) `mkdir build`

(11) `cd build`

(12) `cmake ../`

After carry out the `cmake ../`, I got the following errors, it appears that some libraries were still unfound. See the following figures.

[cmake_error-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gouS2.png)

[cmake_error-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTNnW.png)

So, the `make` definitely failed.

Any ideas?

Thanks.